# Show that $\int_a^{a+T}f(t)dt=\int_0^Tf(t)dt$ for all $a$ when $f$ is $T-$periodic.

Tags: real-analysis

I have to show that $$\int_a^{a+T}f(t)dt=\int_0^Tf(t)dt$$ for all $a$ when $f$ is $T-$periodic. So, I set $t=u+a$ and get $$\int_a^{a+T}f(t)dt=\int_0^T f(u-a)du,$$
but since $f(u-a)\neq f(u)$ when $a\neq T$, I'm stuck. Any idea ?

Comment: Incidentally, what is your assumption on $f$ (or, say, your definition of integral)? Do you assume $f$ continuous? (if so, [Surb's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1902111/75808) is arguably the cleanest).

Answer (score 3):

*This is not the most direct, but I find it slightly more intuitive than just "giving out the answer." Basically, $a$ is an arbitrary number, so it may be easier to decompose it as "multiple of the period, plus remainder.")*

Write $a=k T + b$, with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in[0,T)$.
Then
$$
\int_a^{a+T} f(t)dt = \int_b^{b+T} f(u)du \tag{$t=u+kT$}
$$
and now
$$
\int_a^{a+T} f(t)dt = \int_b^{T} f(u)du + \int_{T}^{b+T} f(u)du
 = \int_b^{T} f(u)du + \int_{0}^{b} f(v)dv
 = \int_0^{T} f(u)du
$$
by changing the variable in the second integral ($v=u-T$).

Comment: It is certainly the most "graphical" answer, thinking about integrals as areas.

Answer (score 3):

**Just an other way**

If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, then set $$g(x)=\int_x^{x+T}f(t)\mathrm d t.$$

You have that $$g'(x)=f(x+T)-f(x)=0,$$ and thus $g$ is constant. The equality follow.

*Notice that if $f\in L^1(0,T)$ only, this proof is not valid.*

Answer (score 0):

Let $I=\displaystyle\int_a^{a+T}f(x)\,dx=\int_a^0f(x)\,dx+\int_0^Tf(x)\,dx+\int_T^{a+T}f(x)\,dx$

$=I_1+I_2+I_3$

Substitute $x-T=u$ in $I_3$ and use $f(u+T)=f(u)$, whence $I_1$ and $I_3$ cancel out and it follows that $I=I_2$.

---

The more general result goes as,

> If $f$ is periodic with period $T$, then $\displaystyle\int_a^{a+nT}f(x)\,dx=n\displaystyle\int_0^Tf(x)\,dx$ $\quad(n\in\mathbb{Z})$